# mysql query results divide into group

Tags: php, mysql

From mysql query, I want make 5 results as a group wrap into a `li` . how to? thanks

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<li>';
if ( ($counter % 5) == 0 ){           
echo '<div class="title">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
}
$counter ++;
echo '</li>';
}
}
```

I want some html output like

```
<li><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div></li>
<li><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div></li>
<li><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div><div class="title">something</div></li>
... <!-- 5 results in one li -->
```

Comment: Can you show the sample HTML that you want to output?

Comment: @spanky, I have update my question. add some sample html what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your mod % either close the `li` or open the `li`, not deal with the `div`.

So something like this:

```
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ( $counter % 5 == 1 ) {           
        echo '<li>';
    }
    echo '<div class="title">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
    if ( $counter % 5 == 0 ) {           
        echo '</li>';
    }
    $counter ++;
}
if ( $counter % 5 != 1 ) {           
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it should help set you on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

You seem very close, how about:

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if (($counter % 5) == 0) {
            echo '<li>';
        }
        echo '<div class="title">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
        if (($counter % 5) == 4) {
            echo '</li>';
        }
        $counter ++;
    }
}
if ($counter % 5 != 4) {           
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Good point; spanky's answer beat me to it, but in any case I edited by answer using his method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = mysqli_num_rows($result);   
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ( ($counter % 5) == 0 ){
echo '<li>'
}           
echo '<div class="title">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
if (((($counter +1) % 5) == 0) || (($counter+1)==$x)){
echo '</li>'
} 
$counter ++;
}
```

I did not check it but the  mysqli_num_rows variable can be used to close last.